# Php if empty variable statement

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm trying to build an if statement for when a variable is filled with a url it will display a button and link to the site, and when the variable is empty the link and button will not display. So far I got it to where it is displays the button and links but making it into an if statement keeps on breaking my site. If you see a problem with the code below, please help. Thanks

```
<div id="social_icon">
<?php if (isset($fburl))
{ 
<a href="<?php echo $options['fburl']; ?>">
<img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5534/9135106179_43deba3d15_o.png"" width="30"    
height="30"></a>; 
}
else
{
//dont show anything
}
?>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use HTML within your PHP code, so PHP sees this as an unexpected variable/string.  Either use `echo` for this, or close the PHP statement, and then write your HTML.

Either:

```
<div id="social_icon">
    <?php if(isset($fburl)){ ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $options['fburl']; ?>">
            <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5534/9135106179_43deba3d15_o.png" width="30" height="30" />
        </a>
    <?php }else{
        //dont show anything
    } ?>   
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div id="social_icon">
    <?php if (isset($fburl)){ 
        echo '<a href="'.$options['fburl'].'"><img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5534/9135106179_43deba3d15_o.png" width="30" height="30" /></a>'; 
    }else{
        //dont show anything
    } ?>   
</div>
```

**Edit**

Actually, I would assume it's not outputting anything because your if statement is checking for `$fburl` whereas you're `echo`ing the link as `$options['fburl']`.  If the facebook url is located at `$options['fburl']`, try:

```
<div id="social_icon">
    <?php if(isset($options['fburl'])){ ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $options['fburl']; ?>">
            <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5534/9135106179_43deba3d15_o.png" width="30" height="30" />
        </a>
    <?php }else{
        //dont show anything
    } ?>   
</div>
```

**Edit 2**

If the options are set but don't contain a link, you will also need check for that:

```
<div id="social_icon">
    <?php if(isset($options['fburl']) && !empty($options['fburl'])){ ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $options['fburl']; ?>">
            <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5534/9135106179_43deba3d15_o.png" width="30" height="30" />
        </a>
    <?php }else{
        //dont show anything
    } ?>   
</div>
```

Comment: it still isn't being called up. I am using Wordpress so the variables are being called in from another .php page. Do you think that might be why it is affecting it to not display?

Comment: What is the HTML output on the page?

Comment: its just blank. Like it shows the div around it and just blank space between them

Comment: sweet. there up now with the thinks and the output are working good. The problem is that when it is not filled it still outputs the a herf to the flicker link.

Comment: I've added another edit.  If the options for those other links are defined but empty, that if statement would still pass.  Checking for a non-empty value would fix that in that case.

Comment: You got it, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error, change it to:

```
<?php if (isset($fburl))
{
//missed end tag here
?>
<a href="<?php echo $options['fburl']; ?>">
<img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5534/9135106179_43deba3d15_o.png"" width="30"    
height="30"></a>; 
<?php
//add another php start tag
}
else
{
//dont show anything
}
?>
```

Comment: That stopped the breaking but now it doesn't display the link at all, even if there is one set.

Comment: It's because you have an error in your syntax.  There's an extra `"` after the src.  I've removed it in my answer.